# Te form and ru form of verbs when used with potential form

Tags: conjugations

What's the difference between using the te form of a verb with the potential form as opposed to just the ru form?

E.g.

> 食べてられない、待ってられない
> 食べられない、待てない

Answer (score 7, accepted):

食べられない is just negative-potential, but 食べてられない is a colloquial version of 食べて**い**られない, which is negative-**progressive**-potential.

- 待てない: I can't wait.
- 待って(い)られない: I can't keep waiting.
- 食べられない: I can't eat it.
- 食べて(い)られない: I can't stay here eating it.

---

**EDIT:** Some more examples:

- 見られない (= 見えない): I can't see it.
- 見て(い)られない: I can't watch it any more. / It's unbearable to see.
- 起きられない: I can't get up (out of bed).
- 起きて(い)られない: I can't stay awake.